# QGIS raster calculator - classification

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, classification

Following the [examples in the QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#examples) I am able to classify a raster using the raster calculator, e.g. based on the aspect derived from a DEM:

```
((aspect@1 > 270) AND (aspect@1 <= 90)) * 1 + ((aspect@1 > 90) AND (aspect@1 <= 270)) * 2
```

This will classify all slightly northward facing slopes as `1` and all facing southward as `2`.

But when I try to mask/take into account areas with little to no slope (less than 3 degrees), the classification wont work properly - not all areas with a slope less than 3 degrees will be classified accordingly.

```
(((aspect@1 > 270) AND (aspect@1 <= 90)) * 1 + ((aspect@1 > 90) AND (aspect@1 <= 270)) * 2) + (slope@1 <= 3) * 3
```

Where am I going wrong? I can't see any logic why some areas are classified as `3`, and others, which should be, aren't. At least there's no wrong classification of areas above 3 degree slope as `3`.

Exemplary images of my problem:

1. The white areas are those with a slope less than 3 degrees.
   [image]
2. The white areas from image 1 aren't uniform anymore, but they should be.
   [image]

Comment: No pixel can have a value less than 90 and greater than 270 at the same time, so it amazes me that the first condition is working as it should. Regarding the second, if it worked well, would not assign 3 to any pixel, but 4 or 5, depending on the aspect, to those with a slope less than 3 degrees, and 1 or 2 for those who do not meet that condition.

Comment: For northward facing slopes it is enough to use this expression:  `aspect@1 > 90 or aspect@1 < 270 ` to include the northern half (from a quarter to until a quarter past, to speakck in the clock-analogy). I don't know why you have such a complicated expression that is even contradictory in itself (as mentioned by @Gabriel De Luca).

Comment: If you want all the cardinal directions (N/E/S/W) to be represented by a quarter-circle, you should change 90 to 45 and 270 to 315, however. An aspect of 89 degrees is nor really oriented to the North, but rather to the East - see: see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasterterrainanalysis.html?#aspect

Comment: Thank you @Babel, but this is a simplified expression for question purposes only ;-)

Comment: @Erik : I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Babel: I meant your second comment. The issue is not the aspects, but the incorporation of the slope.

Comment: Sorry: what does the second image show? If in the first image you had the condition slope <=3, in the second one you added an additional condition - namely: slope <=3 **AND** northward facing aspect, right? So it is logic that you get less pixels for which *both* conditions are fulfilled. The image looks perfectly plausible (as far as I can see without knowing what data you have and what exactly you want to achieve)

Comment: Sorry @Babel, I spent about 4 hours on this yesterday, so I was too deep into it and thought it obvious, that I am trying to classify the DEM according to its aspect, while leaving the rather flat areas for another class.

Comment: Sorry @Erik - still don't understand the problem: why should the white areas of image 2 be uniform? If you combine two conditions, only those areas that match both will get an according value. Terrain is not a uniform surface normally but rugged, so this kind of pattern is absolutely what you should expect. You have small differences in hight between pixels (be it realworld differences in elevation, be it noise/artefacts/rounding erros) and that is reflected in the results. Could you explain a bit more in detail why you think something is not correct - and what?

Comment: @Babel: Everything which is white in image 1 is rather flat - and thus should be a distinct class in image 2. And since I didn't see I combined two conditions, I wondered where I went wrong.

Comment: Also consider that a slope of less than 3 means more or less flat (a plain). A perfectly flat plain (slope of 0) in a narrow sense does not have any aspect, it is **not** oriented to north or any other cardinal direction - or is oriented to all in the same measure. So for extremely flat areas, tiny elevation differences can lead to completely different values for aspect.

Comment: @Erik OK, but you still did not explain what image 2 represents - respectively: how did you create image 2 and how is it related to image 1?

Comment: Can you share the DEM?

Comment: @Babel image 2 was created by an expression following the same logic as the one I used in the second expression in my question. Basically any [EU-DEM](https://land.copernicus.eu/imagery-in-situ/eu-dem/eu-dem-v1.1) can be used, as long as there are some slopes above 3 degree.

Comment: Yeah, but knowing which area you used would help reproducing your image. Did I understand you right: image 1 is slope less than 3, image 2 is slope less than 3 **and** aspect to the north (from 0 to 90 and from 270 to 360 degrees)?

Comment: @Babel here's the DEM: https://www.dropbox.com/s/adek2yab6w331ds/EU-DEM-excerpt.tif?dl=0 - the complete expression I used was `((("aspect@1" < 90) OR ("aspect@1" > 292.5)) * 5 + (("aspect@1" >= 90) AND ("aspect@1" <157.5)) * 3 + (("aspect@1" >= 157.5) AND ("aspect@1" < 225)) * 2 + (("aspect@1" >= 225) AND ("aspect@1" <= 292.5)) * 4) + ("slope@1" <= 3) * 1` - aspect and slope being created using the GDAL tools.

Comment: OK, please can you state exactly all conditions that you want to apply. Your aspect-values here differ from the 90/270 degrees you had initially. You mix up different values for aspects, in the first part it should be < 90, in the second par >=90 at the same time? Sorry, it's extremely confusing and I have difficulty to understand what you're about to do. I would suggest to do a step-by-step approach and produce separate outputs with the raster calculator for each condition, then combine them. Like this, you see if a problem appears. It still seems to me that the output is 100% correct.

Comment: I need five categories: Slopes facing E to SSE (90 to 157.5), SSE to SW (157.5 to 225), SW to WNW (225 to 292.5) and those facing WNW to E (below 90 and above 292.5) - and overriding all these four should be category five, which is flat terrain (slope <= 3°). As stated, I simplified the expression for the sake of this question, but it still faced the same issue, being the flat terrain not overriding all the other categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order not to make mistakes classifying in the raster calculator, it is best to explicitly write the conditions in all terms, taking into account that each term is mutually exclusive from the others :

```
((slope@1 > 3) AND ((aspect@1 <= 90 OR aspect@1 > 270)) * 1 +
((slope@1 > 3) AND ((aspect@1 > 90 AND aspect@1 <= 270)) * 2 +
(slope@1 <= 3) * 3
```

Then, knowing that `True = 1` and that `False = 0`, we can begin to simplify the algebra of sets:

```
(slope@1 > 3) +
(slope@1 > 3) * (aspect@1 > 90) * (aspect@1 <= 270) +
(slope@1 <= 3) * 3
```

Until you get to the simple form:

```
3 - (slope@1 > 3) * (1 + (aspect@1 > 270) + (aspect@1 <= 90))
```

The algebraic operation is not intuitive, but it is useful to understand how it works.

Comment: I know why I dropped out of Mathematics in university. Because I still don't get how you got from step 2 to step 3 - but anyway, step 1 is perfectly logical to me, and seems about right.

Comment: Is not exactly math, but mainly algebra of sets.

Answer (score 2):

You want to categorize your DEM to 5 categories:

1. Slopes > 3 facing to SSE (90 to 157.5) - coded with value of 3
2. Slopes > 3 facing to SW (157.5 to 225)  - coded with value of 2
3. Slopes > 3 facing to WNW (225 to 292.5)  - coded with value of 4
4. Slopes > 3 facing to WNW to E (below 90 and above 292.5) - coded with value of 5
5. Slopes <= 3 (facing any direction)  - coded with value of 1

So you check the DEM for two characteristics: is the slope smaller or larger than 3? And if it is larger than 3: what aspect does it have?

In your expression, however, for conditions 1 to 4 you only check for the aspect and don't include any statement for the slope. You should add an expression that multiplies it with the condition `"slope@1" > 3`: this returns 1 if true (slope larger 3), 0 if false (slope smaller 3). Like this, you get a value of 0 for all conditions from 1 to 4 if the slope is smaller than 3. If it is larger, you get the category values you want (2, 3, 4 or 5).

So simply replace the operator for the last condition from addition (`+`) to multiplication (`*`). The expression in the raster calculator should look like:

```
(
    (
        ("aspect@1" < 90) OR ("aspect@1" > 292.5)
    ) * 5 + 
    (
        ("aspect@1" >= 90) AND ("aspect@1" <157.5)
    ) * 3 + 
    (
        ("aspect@1" >= 157.5) AND ("aspect@1" < 225)
    ) * 2 + 
    (
        ("aspect@1" >= 225) AND ("aspect@1" <= 292.5)
    ) * 4   
) * 
("slope@1" > 3) * 1
```

This is the result, based on the DEM you used - black (pixel-value = 0) is used for more or less flat areas (slope <=3), regardless of aspect:

[image]

Comment: Great breakdown of the calculations/expression, thank you very much.