# Filter for south pointing areas from a DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, aspect

I want to get all south pointing areas within a city. These will be the ideal locations for PV-Plants.

I am aware that a DEM is rasterdata and there is not an attribut table like for shape files/vectordata.

How can I extract just the areas facing south (aspect ratio for a given degree range) in QGIS? The much slower way would be the use of the symbolgy and the colour ramp and look manually.

Comment: Related, though not identical: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408578/qgis-raster-calculator-classification

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can calculate [Aspect](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html#aspect) to get a raster with values ranging from 0-360º, then reclassify south facing values to 1, and the rest to 0/Nodata.

I use [150-210](https://www.openflightschool.de/pluginfile.php/590/mod_book/chapter/375/1024px-Compass_rose_nesw.svg.png) as the definition of south:

First part of the model creates a raster with pixels facing south, second part is vectorizing it and extracts larger continuous polygons.

[image]

[image]